# How can I force Jekyll to always use a UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: ruby, windows, frontend, jekyll, liquid

I've been playing with Jekyll recently to make a personal website. I'm not much of a Ruby programmer, but I know enough Python to get by based on the syntactic similarities. Recently on a Windows machine, I've been running into a problem where multiple encodings (specifically, Windows-1252 and UTF-8) are making their way into the Jekyll build process.

The [only](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7581) two [issues](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5584) on the Jekyll repo were closed with no real resolution. I also found another thing suggesting that I [change the windows console encoding](https://joseoncode.com/2011/11/27/solving-utf-problem-with-jekyll-on-windows/), but that also did nothing to suppress the error, and I kept getting the same issue. Reproduced below:

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/liquid-4.0.3/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:97:in `join': incompatible character encodings: Windows-1252 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

The traceback indicates that the problem is located in `block_body.rb` in the Liquid package, reproduced below (this is not my code, it's directly from the Liquid package):

```
def render(context)
  output = []
  context.resource_limits.render_score += @nodelist.length

  idx = 0
  while node = @nodelist[idx]
    case node
    when String
      check_resources(context, node)
      output << node
    when Variable
      render_node_to_output(node, output, context)
    when Block
      render_node_to_output(node, output, context, node.blank?)
      break if context.interrupt? # might have happened in a for-block
    when Continue, Break
      # If we get an Interrupt that means the block must stop processing. An
      # Interrupt is any command that stops block execution such as {% break %}
      # or {% continue %}
      context.push_interrupt(node.interrupt)
      break
    else # Other non-Block tags
      render_node_to_output(node, output, context)
      break if context.interrupt? # might have happened through an include
    end
    idx += 1
  end

  output.join
end

private
```

The only way I could fix the error (which allowed me to then run Jekyll with no errors and no visible problems with its webpages) was to edit `block_body.rb` directly. I added the following just before `output.join`, to force the encoding to be the same, so that the `join` method would work:

```
   output = output.map{ |i| i.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") }
```

I'm fairly certain that modifying an unfamiliar external package is not the best way to fix this, but it's the only thing that I've tried that has worked so far. Is there something else I could be doing (short of building on Mac/Linux) that would let me solve this encoding problem?

Comment: Are any of your site's files encoded in Windows-1252?

Comment: Don't use Ruby on Windows. I've never met a Ruby developer who successfully and happily used Ruby on Windows. Use something like WSL so you can run Ubuntu on Windows, and then run Ruby in that.